# Automake issue with linking

Tags: c++, automake

I'm working on a library that links another library to use its static functions.

Everything was working perfectly until I switched from including all my code in the header file to sharing it between the .h and .cpp file.

I tried to use `./configure --prefix="<same path as before>"` and then make install but ended up with a `"/usr/bin/install: cannot stat .libs/<library name>.so.0.0.0': No such file or directory"` error. (also, I did change my makefile to accommodate for the inclusion of the .cpp file)

Then, trying to compile my old library (which should've still worked since the linked library didn't make install correctly and was still technically using the older version) I get a pile of errors that seem to have to do with c++ itself. For example:

```
.../gcc/4.9.1/linux64/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/stl_bvector.h:354:13: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
```

There are an absolute ton of errors similar to the one above, all having to do with issues in the path `.../gcc/4.9.1/linux64/include/c++/4.9.1/`

Has anyone run into this error before? Let me know if I need to provide any more information, it's just that I've never had this happen so I'm at a loss as to where to proceed. It's likely something simple I'm missing but the longer I stare at it the less it makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update: I ended up solving the issue I was having. Basically, the .so file was not being accessed, so I used make clean and then the linked library compiled properly. Next, the issues with the base library was just an extra character within a header file that was causing the compiler to blow up with over 1500 lines of errors. After fixing that, it was able to link up properly and is working fine now.